# Get rows based on my given list without revising the order or unique the list

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a df looks like below, I would like to get rows from 'D' column based on my list without changing or unique the order of list. .

```
  A B C D
0 a b 1 1 
1 a b 1 2 
2 a b 1 3 
3 a b 1 4
4 c d 2 5
5 c d 3 6   #df
```

My list

```
l = [4, 2, 6, 4]  # my list

df.loc[df['D'].isin(l)].to_csv('output.csv', index = False)
```

When I use `isin()` the result would change the order and unique my result, `df.loc[df['D'] == value` only print the last line.

```
  A B C D
3 a b 1 4
1 a b 1 2
5 c d 3 6  
3 a b 1 4  # desired output
```

Any good way to do this? Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution without loop but `merge`:

```
In [26]: pd.DataFrame({'D':l}).merge(df, how='left')
Out[26]: 
   D  A  B  C
0  4  a  b  1
1  2  a  b  1
2  6  c  d  3
3  4  a  b  1
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to iterate over your list, get copies of them filtered and then concat them all together

```
l = [4, 2, 6, 4] # you shouldn't use list = as list is a builtin

cache = {}

masked_dfs = []
for v in l:
    try:
        filtered_df = cache[v]
    except KeyError:
        filtered_df = df[df['D'] == v]
        cache[v] = filtered_df

    masked_dfs.append(filtered_df)
new_df = pd.concat(masked_dfs)
```

**UPDATE:** modified my answer to cache answers so that you don't have to do multiple searches for repeats

Answer (score 1):

just collect the indices of the values you are looking for, put in a list and then use that list to slice the data

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
'C' : [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
'D' : [1,2,3,4,5,6]
})
l = [4, 2, 6, 4]

i_locs = [ind for elem in l for ind in df[df['D'] == elem].index]
df.loc[i_locs]
```

results in

```
   C  D
3  3  4
1  5  2
5  1  6
3  3  4
```